# Rejected app :Issue found Invalid Data safety Version code 1

Tags: android, google-play-console

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

Version code 1: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Personal Info Data Type - Email Address

Issue found: Invalid Data safety[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E16xL.jpg)

An application that does not enter data Email Address

Comment: So what is your question actually ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @midhunhk My app was blocked due to a data security claim in which they say my app collects and shares data In a message from Google, there is a problem in the areas above